# Python Web Scrape Not writing To List or Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a few data points off of Home Depot's website and cant seem to get the data to write to the list or data frame. When I print the data instead of append to a list it seems to work fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.homedepot.com/b/Milwaukee/Special-Values/N-5yc1vZ7Zzv'
path = '/Users/Office/Documents/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)
skus = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product-identifier--bd1f5')
prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price-format__main-price')

prod_num = []
prod_price = []

for sku in skus:
    my_sku = sku.find_element_by_class_name('product-identifier--bd1f5').text
    prod_num.append(my_sku)

for price in prices:
    my_price = price.find_element_by_class_name('price-format__main-price').text
    prod_price.append(my_price)

driver.quit()
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price})
df.to_csv('HD_test.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```